# Sending E-Mail via SmtpClient throws exception

Tags: c#, .net, email, mono, smtp

I'm trying to send an E-Mail via C# and Gmail:

```
    // Create the mail client
    var client = new SmtpClient("smtp.google.com", 587)
    {
      DeliveryMethod = SmtpDeliveryMethod.Network,
      UseDefaultCredentials = false,
      EnableSsl = true,
      Credentials = new NetworkCredential("MYADDRESS@gmail.com", "MYPASSWORD")
    };

    // Create the message
    var msg = new MailMessage("MYADDRESS@gmail.com", "MYADDRESS@gmail.com")
    {
      Subject = "My Subject"
    };

    // Send the mail
    client.Send(msg);
```

This code is built from examples taken from the web (mostly this site). Sadly it does not work. Instead it throws an exception:

> {System.Net.Mail.SmtpException: Message could not be sent. --->
>   System.Net.Sockets.SocketException: Could not resolve host
>   'smtp.google.com'   at System.Net.Dns.Error_11001 (System.String
>   hostName) [0x00000] in
>   /private/tmp/source-mono-mac-3.12.0-branch-32/bockbuild-mono-3.12.0-......

My computer can reach "smtp.google.com" just fine. Even pinging it in my C# program works. Only the SmtpClient cannot resolve the host.

What could I try to fix this problem? Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe your issue is in your `SmtpClient`.  The client information for Google would be as follows:

- `smtp.gmail.com`

So your code should be as follows:

```
var client = new SmtpClient("smtp.gmail.com", 587);
```

From what I can currently see, I'd recommend *checking* Google's documentation about how to use their *relay / mail service*.